# Libvirt/KVM support for partiitoned memory

Tags: kvm-virtualization, memory, libvirt

Does KVM/Libvirt support partitioned memory? Is it possible to make sure that two VMs do not have memory-mapping that overlaps?

Answer (score 2):

You can pre-allocate HugePages for each VM.

If you turn off Kernel Samepage Merging (KSM) on the hypervisor, then its kernel will not try to find common memory pages and map one to the other.